# Django 2.0.7 how URL app_name works

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, url, django-2.0

I'm working on a project built with python 3.4.3 and django 2.0.7 and I'm stuck with URLs files logic. I still haven't figured this error out: "ImportError: No module named 'fields'.

Here's what I have:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from bridge.core import views as core_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', core_views.home),
    path('backoffice/fields/', include('fields.urls', namespace='backoffice')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**fields/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'fields'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.list_fields, name='list_fields'),
]
```

What does "app_name" is supposed to be filled with? How "app_name" works?

According to there files, when I submit "/backoffice/fields/" in the browser django should invoke "views.list_fields", shouldn't?

If any other information is required to help me with this issue, just let me know and I'll provide it as quickly as possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add `fields` in your installed apps in the `settings`?

Comment: Yes, INSTALLED_APPS = [ ..., 'bridge.fields',]

Comment: When you created your app where the `fields.urls` is located, what did you call it?

Comment: Well, I didn't move any files, so they are now where they were when I created the app: /urls.py and /fields/urls/py

Comment: Is the name of your project `bridge`?

Comment: Change installed apps from `bridge.fields` to just `fields` and see what happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `app_name` is used to reference your `urls` else where. You will also see referenced as `namespacing`. If you would have two different apps with the same `url name`, it wouldn't always pick the right one. So you namespace them and call them as such:

```
{% url 'employee:name' %}
{% url 'customer:name' %}
```

You can use the names in more than just template tags, like `reverse('employee:name')` and such.

The problem you are running into is that it doesn't know where to find your `urls` file. If your installed app is `bridge.fields`, try using `include(bridge.fields.urls)`.

To fully find your problem I would have to see you `project` folder structure as to where your main `urls` file is and where your `fields.urls` is. Remember that `fields.urls` really means a file named `urls.py` that is located in the folder named `fields`.

Comment: You nailed it! I don't know exactly why, but the problem was my `include(fields.urls)`. I changed it to `include(bridge.fields.urls)` and now it's working just fine. Probably somehow the file `fields.urls` was not being found and the routes weren't being included properly. Thank you @CarlBrubaker

Comment: It's because that is what called it in your installed apps